# Generate list of objects from XML stored in SqlXml variable

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have `BIObject` class

```
public class BIObject
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

and also have below XML

```
<root>
  <objects>
    <object database="LynxReporting" schema="dbo" name="rptusp_GLTDRSummary" type="P"/>
    <object database="IntraDay" schema="dbo" name="BMHGLCloseDetails" type="T"/>
    <object database="LynxReporting" schema="dbo" name="factGeneralLedger" type="P"/>
  </objects>
</root>
```

I need to create `List<IBObject>` from the XML

**Note: I load the XML from database into a property of type SqlXml** so I need to convert SqlXml to `List<IBObject>`

Looked at couple of answers but could not figure out how I can do that.

EDIT:

I used below code

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(myXmlString))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BIObject>));
    List<BIObject> objs = (List<BIObject>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

but got error

> There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

and

> root xmlns='' was not expected.

Comment: Use [XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for hint. Please check my edit to see what I already have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which "represent" your xml structure

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class BIObjects
{
    public BIObjects() 
    {
        Objects = new List<BIObject>();
    }

    [XmlArray("objects")]
    [XmlArrayItem("object")]
    public List<BIObject> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class BIObject
{
    [XmlAttribute("database")]
    public string Database { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("schema")]
    public string Schema { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

Then use same serializer code you provide in the question

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(myXmlString))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BIObjects));
    var objs = (BIObjects)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    // use results
    // foreach(BIObject obj in objs.Objects)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.